# Combining multiple indicators with different time frames in a strategy

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I'm pretty new here; a very nice and helpful place.

I'm trying to combine multiple indicators in a Tradingview Strategy with Pine Script.
This is the Built-in code of Supertrend:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Supertrend", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

atrPeriod = input(10, "ATR Length")
factor = input.float(3.0, "Factor", step = 0.01)

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(factor, atrPeriod)

bodyMiddle = plot((open + close) / 2, display=display.none)
upTrend = plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
downTrend = plot(direction < 0? na : supertrend, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr)

fill(bodyMiddle, upTrend, color.new(color.green, 90), fillgaps=false)
fill(bodyMiddle, downTrend, color.new(color.red, 90), fillgaps=false)
```

I want to use Supertrend in 30M time frame. I cannot change the value of `timeframe=""`because it's a single indicator. I'm working on a strategy and there things got changed.

"While" supertrend (30M) is in Uptrend condition, I want to apply (buy/sell) built in MFI indicator in 15M time frame. Here is the built-in MFI:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Money Flow Index", shorttitle="MFI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
length = input.int(title="Length", defval=14, minval=1, maxval=2000)
src = hlc3
mf = ta.mfi(src, length)
plot(mf, "MF", color=#7E57C2)
overbought=hline(80, title="Overbought", color=#787B86)
oversold=hline(20, title="Oversold", color=#787B86)
fill(overbought, oversold, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")
```

and when the trend changes into downtrend, I don't want to use MFI anymore but wanna use Bollinger Bands in 1H time frame "while" supertrend (30M) is in Downtrend condition. Here is Built-in Bollinger Bands:

```
//@version=5
indicator(shorttitle="BB", title="Bollinger Bands", overlay=true, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")
basis = ta.sma(src, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
offset = input.int(0, "Offset", minval = -500, maxval = 500)
plot(basis, "Basis", color=#FF6D00, offset = offset)
p1 = plot(upper, "Upper", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
p2 = plot(lower, "Lower", color=#2962FF, offset = offset)
fill(p1, p2, title = "Background", color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95))
```

I think I need to use `request.security()` function for different time frames in same strategy and `if & else` for turning one indicator on/of while up or downtrend condition of Supertrend but I really don't understand how to build it. I appreciate any answers and thanks in advance

Comment: My suggestion is forget about different timeframes and try to write everything for the same timeframe. See if you are able to pull that off. If you can apply your algorithm to same timeframe, you can use `request.security()` for the different timeframes.